# Load data from this file. (load as EXCEL or CSV)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader, regexp-replace

```
EmpId      Name
----------------------                                                                                 
E0008      Mary _Jane
EMP0009    PeterParker
10         Jack roger
EMP 0012   Mark Todd
EMP0011    John Smith
EMP13      *Peter Parker
```

Need to satisfy below conditions

1. Load data from this file (load as EXCEL or CSV)
2. While loading data create multiple batches
3. While loading data, apply below rules

   - (a) Remove extra spaces in Name column and replace with single space
   - (b) Where there is no space between First and lastname add a space
   - (c) In name, remove any special characters
   - (d) In name, Change to title case
   - On EmpID remove all special characters and EmpID should be in EMP0011 format.

My control is below

```
load data

infile 'E:\A\Book2.csv'

TRUNCATE

PRESERVE BLANKS

into table dummy

fields terminated by ',' 

optionally enclosed by '"'AND'"'

(

 EMPID "CASE WHEN SUBSTR(:EMPID,1,1)='E' THEN 'EMP00'||SUBSTR(:EMPID,-2) ELSE 
'EMP00'||SUBSTR(:EMPID,-2) END",

 NAME "INITCAP(REGEXP_REPLACE(:NAME,'[^A-Z a-z]'))"

)
```

I'm unable to satisfy conditions 2, 3b, 3d

Comment: Are you using Oracle or SQLite?

Comment: Do you have to use SQL*Loader to load the CSV file into Oracle database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the following example.

Control file:

```
load data 
infile *
replace
into table dummy
fields terminated by ";" 
trailing nullcols
(
empid "'EMP' || lpad(regexp_substr(:empid, '[[:digit:]]+$'), 4, '0')",
name  "trim(initcap(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(:name, '[^[:alnum:] ]'), '([[:upper:]])', ' \\1'), ' +', ' ')))"
)

begindata
E0008;Mary _Jane
EMP0009;PeterParker
10;Jack roger
EMP 0012;Mark  Todd
EMP0011;John Smith
EMP13;*Peter Parker
```

Loading session and the result:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@kc11gt control=test32.ctl log=test32.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Uto Ruj 1 10:18:01 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 5
Commit point reached - logical record count 6

SQL> select * from dummy;

EMPID      NAME
---------- --------------------
EMP0008    Mary Jane
EMP0009    Peter Parker
EMP0010    Jack Roger
EMP0012    Mark Todd
EMP0011    John Smith
EMP0013    Peter Parker

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

What does the control file do?

For `EMPID`: as it must begin with `EMP`, it is set to be a constant. Digits within input data are left padded with zeros up to 4 characters in length.

For `NAME`:

- the innermost regexp `[^[:alnum:] ]` removes anything but alphanumerics and spaces
- one level up regexp `'([[:upper:]])', ' \\1'` adds space in front of every uppercase letter
- one more level up regexp `' +', ' '` replaces multiple spaces with a single space
- `INITCAP` capitalizes first letters in every word
- `TRIM` removes leading (and trailing) spaces